# NSString from C to Swift

Tags: swift

I code only been a short time and started with Swift .

Can me somebody convert the String in Swift?

Or can me give Tipps?

The main problem lies the selectedSegmentIndex?

```
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%ld%@", tag , button.selectedSegmentIndex?@"L" : @"H"];
```

greetings

Comment: What did you try, and how did this fail?  Maybe working through a swift tutorial might help?

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not C, but Objective-C. If you are not interested in learning about Objective-C at this time and do not need explanation of the above code, this should work:

```
var response = String(format: "P%ld%@", tag, button.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "L" : "H")
```